# Show a single thumbnail when posting on facebook

Tags: vb.net, facebook, facebook-opengraph

A little background info is that my team and I developed a website for a Real Estate Agency and I've been assigned the task of setting the image of the currently selected property into facebook's sharing feature.

The webpage for the property is dynamic as there are several listings, so what I've done is select the first image that is loaded on the page and set it to the **og:image** meta tag.

Now let's say I copy the URL and post it on Facebook, it'll show the correct thumbnail, HOWEVER, it'll also show multiple thumbnails from other listings.

[image]

All images on the website are over 200 x 200px and are within an aspect ratio of 3:1.

My question is, how do I tell Facebook to only take my initial image and not grab others while it's as it. 
Is there perhaps a SelectSingleImage property that I can apply?

I've already spent more time searching for the answer to this issue than I would have liked, so thanks for any help provided, it's much appreciated.

Comment: Is there only one `og:image` tag on each URL?

Comment: Correct. When viewing the source of my page, there is a single og:image meta tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Facebook saved those images in cache for some bizarre reason, but to resolve this issue all I had to do was enter the URL into Facebook's [Linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) tool which in turn cleared the cache on their server.

Answer (score 0):

One method I use sometimes is to recognize Facebook's server and simply provide it with different data. This way you can actually only have one image on the page (as far as Facebook knows).

I don't know anything about [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net), but here is a simple code sample in PHP. All it does is perform a regular expression on the user agent of the request to match it against the string `"facebook"`.

```
$isFacebook = false;
if(preg_match("/facebook/",strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]))) {
  $isFacebook = true;
}
```

Facebook may very well change their user agent signature one day, but for now, I'm pretty sure you'll be safe but keep synced with the [Developers Blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/) and the [Roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap).